# Assigning only part of a string to a variable in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I receive from the user a certain absolute filepath, and I want to create a variable that will be a string that won't include only the **FIRST** two components of the file path, but without printing it or anything.

For example, the absolute path could be:

```
/home/myusername/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

And it's saved in "target_path", and I want "mydir" to be only:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

I tried using the cut command in different ways but without success.

Comment: Is `/home/username` the actual `$HOME` directory of the invoking user? if so you could remove it simply using `mydir="${target_path#$HOME}"` I think

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [bash's string manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string):

```
$ a=/home/myusername/folder1/folder2/folder3
$ echo "${a#/*/*/}"
folder1/folder2/folder3
```

So, the string you want would be (adding back the leading slash):

```
b="/${a#/*/*/}"
```

For a variable `a`, `${a#foo}` will remove the shortest string matching `foo` from the *start* of `a`. So, we remove the shortest string containing three `/` (including the leading slash in the path), to remove the first two components of the absolute path.

Comment: The path might be 30 folders, and I only want to include the last 28. Will this still work?

Comment: @Lifeofpi why not?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example using `cut`

```
echo "/home/myusername/folder1/folder2/folder3" | cut -d '/' -f4- 

folder1/folder2/folder3
```

If you need the leading `/` you could append `| sed 's/^/\//'` to the end of your line.

You need `-f4-` because `-d '/'` tells `cut` to use `/` as a delimiter between fields. So the first field comes before the first delimiter, in this case the first field is empty. So `folder1` is the 4th field and `-f4-` tells cut to use all fields from the 4th onwards.

Answer (score 7):

You can use bash parameter expansion like so:

```
target_path=/home/username/folder1/folder2/folder3
myvar="/${target_path#/*/*/}"
```

After this:

```
echo $myvar
```

gives:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

It works by removing the first match of the pattern `/*/*/` from your target_path variable, by using the `${target_path#pattern}` shell parameter expansion syntax. Unfortunately this removes the first `/` character, which is why that character must be explicitly included while setting the myvar variable.

**Warning:** You should check that your target_path variable contains some characters, and is longer than two path segments before using this method. For instance if `target_path=/home/username/`, then `myvar=/`. This could be dangerous to your system if you're running something like `rm -rf "$myvar"*`. **Don't try this!**

Comment: The path might be 30 folders, and I only want to include the last 28. Will this still work?

Comment: Definitely, this will only trim the first two, no matter what length the path is.